# How do I order strings of length N and 2 bits?

Tags: string, function, combinations, bit, string-length

I have a string of length N with 2 bits. I am trying to find a function to order these strings. For example:

F(110) = 1

F(101) = 2

F(011) = 3

The strategy I adopted was labeling the bits by their position, so that for the first case K=1 and L=2 and hence

F(1,2) = 1

F(1,3) = 2

F(2,3) = 3

Does anyone have an idea of what this function might be?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Do mean to say _I have strings of length N, each string has 2 bit set to '1' and all remaining bits set to '0'_?   If so, this is a plain numeric (if the "strings" are actually numbers) or alphabetic __sort__ of the input strings.

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with actual strings, sort them alphabetically ascending. If you are dealing with integers, there are some workarounds:

- Convert the integer into bit-strings and sort alphabetically ascending.

or

- Reverse the bits in the integer (`011` becomes `110`) and sort numerically ascending.

However, these workarounds might be slow. The function F described by you turns out to be pretty simple (assuming you are given the positions of the 1-bits) and is therefore a good solution.

To come up with an implementation of F we first look at the sequence of all bit-strings with exactly two 1-bits. Here we don't care about the length of the bit-string. We simply increment the bit-strings from left to right (opposed to the usual Arabic interpretation of numbers where you increment from right to left).

Next to the actual bit-string I replaced all `0` by `.`, the left `1` by `l`, and the right `1` by `r`. This makes it easier to see the pattern.

```
 1:   11       lr
 2:   101      l.r
 3:   011      .lr
 4:   1001     l..r
 5:   0101     .l.r
 6:   0011     ..lr
 7:   10001    l...r
 8:   01001    .l..r
 9:   00101    ..l.r
10:   00011    ...lr
11:   100001   l....r
 …    …        …
```

The function F is supposed to count the steps needed to increment to a given bit-string.
In the following, L is the index of the left 1-bit and R is the index of the right 1-bit. As in your question, we use 1-based indices. That is, the leftmost character in a string has index 1

For the right 1-bit to move one position to the right, the left 1-bit has to "*catch up*". If the left 1-bit starts at L=1 then catching up takes R-1 steps (when counting the start step L=1 too). For the right 1-bit to reach a high position, the left 1-bit has to catch up multiple times, as it is returned to the start each time the right 1-bit moves one to the right. Each time, catching up takes a little bit longer as the right 1-bit is further away from the start. The first time it takes 1 step, then 2, then 3, and so on. Thus, For the right 1-bit to reach position R it takes 1+2+3+…+(R-1) steps = (R-1)·(R-2)/2 steps. After that, we only have to move the left 1-bit to its position, which takes L steps. Therefore the function is

**F(L,R) := (R-1)·(R-2) / 2 + L**

Note that this function only is easy to implement if you know L and R. If you have an integer and would need to determine L and R first, it might be easier and faster to reverse the integer instead and sort numerically ascending. Determining L and R might be slower than reversing the bits in the integer.